# How to get JSON response from google places API in android?

Tags: android, json, google-api, google-places-api

Can anyone share a snippet that elaborates how to get JSON response ( IN ANDROID) from call to Google Places API?
How do I call API? How do I pass parameters and How do I get JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [Sprockets](https://github.com/pushbit/sprockets-android) (disclosure: I'm the developer).  It provides a [Java API](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/google/Places.html) on top of the Google Places API, so you can query it using various methods like:

```
Places.textSearch(Params.create().query("pizza near times square"))
```

The library also provides a [GooglePlaceAutoComplete](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/widget/GooglePlaceAutoComplete.html) widget and a [GooglePlacesLoader](https://pushbit.github.io/sprockets-android/apidocs/index.html?net/sf/sprockets/content/GooglePlacesLoader.html).